# Activity not passing intent to onActivityResult()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

This is the Kotlin main activity, which is having problems receiving data from the second activity (posted after this)

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    private val LOG_TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName


    val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.android.twoactivities.extra.MESSAGE"

    val TEXT_REQUEST = 1



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }


    fun launchSecondActivity(view: View) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Button clicked!")


        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)



        val message = "${editText_main.text}"



        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


        startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST)

        editText_main.text.clear()

    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

       if (requestCode == TEXT_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                val reply = intent.getStringExtra(SecondActivity().EXTRA_REPLY)






                (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_header_reply) as TextView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                (findViewById(R.id.text_message_reply) as TextView).setText(reply)


            }
        }



    }
}
```

This is the second activity,

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TEXT_REQUEST = 1

    val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.twoactivities.extra.REPLY"





    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        var message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity().EXTRA_MESSAGE)

        val textView2 = findViewById(R.id.text_message) as TextView


        if (textView2 != null) {
            textView2.setText(message)
        }

    }


    fun returnReply(view: View) {



        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        val reply = "${editText_second.text}"


        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, reply)
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REPLY), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


        startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST)
        finish()


    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code? The TEXT_REQUEST and RESULT CODE aren't passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this code from `SecondActivity`:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST)
```

and in `MainActivity.onActivityResult()` change this:

```
val reply = intent.getStringExtra(SecondActivity().EXTRA_REPLY)
```

to this:

```
val reply = data.getStringExtra(SecondActivity().EXTRA_REPLY)
```

You are trying to get the returned "reply" from the wrong `Intent`.

Comment: The code is now functional. What's the rationale behind omitting startActivityForResult?

Comment: `MainActivity` launches `SecondActivity` by calling `startActivityForResult()`. That means that the "result" will be returned to `MainActivity` when `SecondActivity` finishes. This happens automagically. All you need to do is to set your "result" in `SecondActivity` and then call `finish()`. At that point, `SecondActivity` is removed from the task stack and Android goes back to `MainActivity` and delivers the "result" by calling `MainActivity.onActivityResult()`. I hope that's clear now.

Comment: Also, if this answer was helpful you should "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. That will remove the question from the list of unananswered questions and may help someone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST)` from second activity and check what result are you getting?